# proof of identity with integer function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a direct derivation proof for this following identity?

$$\sum^{\big[\frac{n}{3}\big]}_{k=0}\big[\frac{n-3k}{2}\big]=\big[\frac{n^2+2n+4}{12}\big]$$

Comment: Are we assuming $3\vert n$?

Comment: @EliSadoff not necessarily.